# Storing the data once entered in Scanner to be saved in various Arrays. Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have run into a wall here trying to figure out how to make it save the data entered in by a user when prompted for information to add a new employee to a database. I currently have it as option = "done" but I am sure there is a better way or I guess a correct way to do this.

```
public void addemployee(){

    System.out.println("Enter employee's name, ID, and Salary separated by comma... enter 'done' once finished.");

    String option = "";

    String array []= new String[3];

    int id = 0;

     

    while (!option.equals("done")) {

       option = scan.nextLine();

        if (!option.equals("done")) {

            array = option.split("");
            name[id] = array [1].trim();

            number[id] = array [2].trim();

            salary [id] = array [3].trim();

            id++;


menu();
```

I just end up getting a neverending cycle with no data being saved
3: Retrieve data by employee id

4: Retrieve employee list based on salary range

5: Exit

Please choose option:
1
Enter employee's name, ID, and Salary separated by comma... enter 'done' once finished.
Patrick,55455,70000 done
*****Employee Data*****

0: Load employee data

1: Add employee

2: Display all employees

3: Retrieve data by employee id

4: Retrieve employee list based on salary range

5: Exit

Please choose option:

Comment: instead of doing like that,

while(sc.hasNext()) {
    option = sc. nextLine();
    if(option.equals("done")) {
        break;
    }
    //remaining operations
}

Comment: Also, I will suggest you create an employee object to store the employee data and save it as batch insertion (list<Employee>).

Comment: Can you please format your question?